# Sony Walkman MP3 player not mounting in Xubuntu 11.10

Tags: automount, xubuntu, mp3-player

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 11.10 with `xubuntu-desktop` installed over it (I don't like Unity), and have found that when I plug in my Sony Walkman NWZ-B153 MP3 player, it does not mount as expected.

I have checked on `lsusb` and the device is recognised, Rhythmbox also picks up the MP3 player and shows it in the 'devices' list.

However, I cannot browse the MP3 player's files through either pcmanfm or thunar. I installed the `usbmount` package and this seems to have preemptively solved the problem for other USB devices, as I can access other USB pen drives through the `/media/usb/` address.

The MP3 seems to show itself nowhere except through Rhythmbox and `lsusb` so if someone can offer a solution so I can browse its files, that would be greatly appreciated.

I know this sort of question has been asked a lot, but none of the provided answers give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Players like these have two operation modes:

1. MTP device (Microsoft's Media Transfer Protocol)
2. USB drive.

When the device is in mode MTP, it can't be accessed in mode USB; changing modes may take several seconds. MTP is broken by design while the open source `libmtp` effort gives a valiant fight to support flawed players and fails / succeeds / fails from release to release. (10.04 was most stable since 7.04 or so)

My experience with a NWZ-A729 and 11.10 is that it works with Gnomad2 only if you start Gnomad2 before plugging in the device. USB drive access works only if you don't start any jukebox software before plugging it in.

YMMV.